# iSeries DB2 SQL - Update Variable in UDF Using CASE Statement

Tags: sql, db2, user-defined-functions, ibm-midrange, case-statement

I am attempting to create a user defined function for DB2 and cannot figure it out.  I am much more comfortable with t-sql, which would do this in about a dozen ways.  I need help as all I get in return are cryptic error messages that tell me there are no valid tokens or some such.

The basic premise is that I am trying to convert a normal date into a date format used throughout the database (cyymmdd)  Here goes the pseudo-code:

```
Get current time;
If YEAR(current time) > 1999 then 1 else 0;
```

Simple enough, right?  Can't get it to work.
Here is the actual code:

```
DECLARE Cn CHAR ( 1 ) ;
CASE
WHEN YEAR(X) > 1999
THEN SET Cn = 1;
ELSE SET Cn = 0;
```

Also tried:

```
DECLARE Cn CHAR ( 1 ) ;
CASE YEAR(X)
WHEN  > 1999
THEN SET Cn = 1;
ELSE SET Cn = 0;
```

And that fails miserably as it should.

I am really at a loss as to how I can convert 3/25/2014 into 1140325 with just SQL.  I guess I can handle this in application logic, but that isn't the way I want to go with this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You may want to show the entire source of your function, because the fragments you've included don't seem to have valid syntax. Knowledge of T-SQL is no substitute for reading the [actual manuals](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzcasestmt.htm). Also, why are you assigning integer values to a `CHAR(1)` variable?

Comment: @mustaccio, yes the syntax is incorrect in some manner.  I tried many variations based on samples from the ibm website, but kept getting errors.  If I can simply get a case statement to work, I can handle the logic to finish out the function.  However, it looks as though James showed us a better way to convert the dates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a simple calculation to convert a DATE to CYMD:

```
SELECT (YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - 1900) * 10000 
  + MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) * 100 
  + DAY(CURRENT_DATE)
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

---

A UDF to perform the conversion:

```
CREATE FUNCTION QGPL.DATE2CYMD(DATE DATE) RETURNS DEC(7)
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    RETURN (YEAR(DATE) - 1900) * 10000
    + MONTH(DATE) * 100
    + DAY(DATE);
END
```

A test to verify it's working correctly:

```
SELECT 
    QGPL.DATE2CYMD(CURRENT_DATE) CURRENT_CYMD, 
    QGPL.DATE2CYMD(CAST(NULL AS DATE)) NULL_CYMD
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks James, that was much simpler than the path I was heading down.  UDF now working!

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, you can think of `CASE` as if it was a function. A `CASE` structure selects an *expression*; it doesn't execute statements. In effect, it returns a value as a function or any *expression* would.

Here are some coding variations that all result in MYCENT getting either '1' or '0' set:

```
DECLARE MYCENT CHAR ( 1 ) ;
DECLARE MYYEAR BIGINT ;

 SET MYYEAR = YEAR ( CURRENT DATE ) ;
 SET MYCENT = CASE WHEN MYYEAR > 1999 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END ;
or
 IF ( MYYEAR > 1999 )
    THEN SET MYCENT = '1' ;
    ELSE SET MYCENT = '0' ;
 END IF ;

 SET MYCENT = CASE WHEN YEAR(CURRENT DATE) > 1999 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END ;
```

Note that the two CASE examples both use a single `WHEN...THEN...` clause, but you can have as many as needed. Also note that using `IF` has a `SET` statement in each branch, but `CASE` simply chooses a value to return. (The value is a form of *expression*.)

As a syntactic element of SQL, `CASE` is known as a *case-expression*. As an *expression*, you can generally use `CASE` wherever a variable might be valid.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get a case statement working in a function.  That will be handy in the future.